# How to change default image for pointer

Tags: html, css, pointers, mouse-cursor

I need to change the default image for cursor: pointer with some custom image.

To create a class and specify the hover value for cursor is not a valid solution since I would have to add that class to all elements already made and is you know... not exactly optimal. Also can't add that class to body since the children with cursor: pointer would overwrite it.

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to change the default image for cursor: pointer with some custom image.

I misunderstood that at first, but after reading [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368502/html-css-cursor-how-to-change-default-image-for-pointer/12369387#comment16612213_12368621), things were clearer.

You can do this easily using jQuery/JavaScript. First, here's the slightly-simpler jQuery version:

```
$("*").each(function() {
    var cur = $(this);
    if(cur.css("cursor") == "pointer") {
       cur.css("cursor", "url(newcursor.ico)");
    }
});
```

Pure JavaScript version:

```
var elms = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
var n = elms.length;
for(var i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
    if(window.getComputedStyle(elms[i]).cursor == "pointer") {
        elms[i].style.cursor = "url(newcursor.ico)";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup. This seems like what I need. I doesn't seem ideal with js but is better than the other way. One quick question... isn't this a bit let's say... processor expensive (since it seems I need to check this at mouse move to check for hovers)?

Comment: @zozo Nope, you don't check at mousemove, you just do it once. You look for elements that have a `pointer` cursor by default, and use your custom cursor instead.

Comment: Yes but what if there is a pointer on hover. Those won't be found at that search.

Comment: @zozo They will be found by that search.

Answer (score 8):

You can create a custom `cursor` for the `body` element, which will, unless overridden by later selectors, serve to act as a default:

```
body {
    cursor: URL(images/cursorimage.cur); /* IE */
    cursor: URL(images/cursorimage.gif);
}
```

Comment: I don't need the cursor to look somehow. I need the cursor to look somehow when is a pointer. That changes the cursor to be something. If is pointer is still the hand.

Comment: In which case, I think you're going to be stuck with specifying a particular cursor image for all elements that would cause the cursor to be a `pointer`. So, `a`, `button` {/*...*/}` etc.

Comment: This sucks :| Is exactly what I was trying to evade.

Comment: Yeah, it's not ideal, but I'm not aware of any means by which one could express 'the `pointer` cursor should look like this' in CSS. And even in JavaScript, I think it'd essentially have to be done the same way. =/

Comment: @zozo In that case, please take a look at my answer for a solution using JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

yes you can do this easily as like this

```
   .anyclass{
    cursor: URL(images/cursorimagefule.gif);
    }
```

image file must be 32x32 or smaller

apparently internet explorer only supports .cur files

***[more info](http://webdesign.about.com/od/styleproperties/a/aa060607.htm)***

Comment: Not down-voting, but the question does explicitly state: *To create a class and specify the hover value for cursor is not a valid solution since I would have to add that class to all elements already made.*

Comment: Not what the OP requires, [refer to this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368502/html-css-cursor-how-to-change-default-image-for-pointer/12369387#comment16612213_12368621).

Comment: Plus one for the size limit!

Answer (score 1):

None of these worked for me. I had to use this slightly different syntax. Notice the lowercse 'url' , the quotes around the path, and adding of !important. Also, any size works.

```
body {
  cursor: url("mouseSm.png"), auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `cursor` 
options are can be found here
http://www.echoecho.com/csscursors.htm
for image you can use

```
cursor:url(uri)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the "cursor" property is the same as with any CSS property- simply apply it to the desired element:

```
<style type="text/css">
body{
    cursor: url(mycursor.cur)
}
</style>
```

This changes the default arrow cursor of a webpage to a custom image instead.