# Multiple custom cursors

Tags: css

I understand that you can use CSS to change the cursor between the default and to a custom URL, and I know that you can set specific cursors for specific elements.
What I want to do is set cursors for the defaults so that when the user hovers over any element which brings up the click finger cursor, my own custom click finger will appear.

To explain it another way, imagine a selector that instead of running whenever the user hovers over a certain element, it would run whenever the web page changes the cursor to one of the default.

I think that I have done an ok job of explaining this but if I don't make sense I will happily explain further.

Comment: If you are looking into substituting the default cursor, I think that can only be done [through javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368502/html-css-cursor-how-to-change-default-image-for-pointer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do this using Javascript:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
// gets array of every element
for(var counter = 0; counter < elements.length; i ++) {
// loops through every element
if(window.getComputedStyle(elements[counter]).cursor == "pointer") {
// checks if the element uses a "pointer" cursor
    elements[counter].style.cursor = "url(/*   Your cursor's URL   */)";
// if it does, the cursor is replaced with yours
}
}
```

Comment: sorry, I am not good with javascript. how would I put my cursors url in the code above? I tried replacing everything between the brackets but I get an error.

Comment: You would want to replace the the thing that says `/* Your cursor's URL  */` with the url. `/* */` means a comment in the code that doesn't affect anything. 

For example, it would say `elements[counter].style.cursor = "url(images/cursor.png)";` If your cursor was named `cursor.png` under the folder `images`.

Comment: yeah I know commenting and I tried that and it didn't work. I was wondering if there was something specific to JS that I was missing.

Comment: In theory, it should work. I'll do a little fiddling around and find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For a customer CSS cursor its much like any other CSS element use url()

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor?v=example

```
cursor: url(path/to/image), auto;
```

No need for javascript if you wanted this to be on every link then:

```
a:hover{
   cursor: url(path/to/image), auto;
}
```